# Is there any efficient way get the left physical memory in docker?

Tags: c, linux, docker, linux-kernel

My app program wants to read free avail physical memory in docker.

Currently，which means I can think of,  it is reading two values `memory.limit_in_bytes` and `memory.usage_in_bytes` from the 'cgroup' file in docker, then figuring them out as

```
free_memory = value memory.limit_in_bytes - memory.usage_in_bytes
```

but this will be very slow.

Is there any efficient way to get free physical memory?

My app focuses on performance so much.

Comment: "*but this will be very slow*", how do you know? how did you test it?

Comment: Have you calculated the computational cost of this operation? What will be the frequency of this function call? How many times per second?

Besides, are you planning to change the limits on the fly from within the container? Or from outside the container? If not, probably you can track your own usage of the used byte and refer to the initial read of the limit

Comment: I am facing this issue too. Let me elaborate a bit: memory.usage_in_bytes grows along with allocation and also with page caching.  In example: mapping, viewing and unmapping a file (and waiting for Shared Dirty and Clean memory to be zeroed) - will NOT reduce usage_in_bytes.  The memory goes to cached memory (referenced to the process in hand). Because there is no real way to know how much memory is cached, only `sysctl -w vm.drop_cache=1/3..etc.` can help, but the question is : How to know how much cached memory there is to free.   So I am +1 this question

Answer (score 0):

My answer to this question: you can't really know the exact value from inside the docker instance (see my comment above).
My own solution for this problem leans on the fact I know there's only a single process running, there for its RSS reflects (more or less) the total physical RAM consumed by the container.
So.. instead of `free_memory = value memory.limit_in_bytes - memory.usage_in_bytes` I used `free_memory = value memory.limit_in_bytes - /proc/<pid>/stats::VmRSS`
True, this is not accurate, but this is the closest way I found for getting the real value.